# Swift - How to send POST request with "x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, urlencode

I searched a lot and there's no clear instruction for sending POST request with "x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type.
i want to know how to do that and if you know how to do it with Alamofire it would be even better.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hope you are searching for this one or give us more explanation in code so we get it easily:

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]
let parameters = [

]

Alamofire.request("urlString", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
    case.success(let data):
        print("success",data)
    case.failure(let error):
        print("Not Success",error)
        self.view.makeToast(message: "Server Error!!")
    }

}
```

Comment: how to send parameters with it ?

Answer (score 4):

I used below code in swift 4.2

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.88.129:81/authenticate") else {
        return
    }


    let user1 = username.text!
    let pass = passwordfield.text!
    print(user1)
    print(pass)
    let data : Data = "username=\(user1)&password=\(pass)&grant_type=password".data(using: .utf8)!
    var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type");
    request.setValue(NSLocalizedString("lang", comment: ""), forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept-Language");
    request.httpBody = data

    print("one called")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    // vs let session = URLSession.shared
      // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

         if let error = error
        {
            print(error)
        }
         else if let response = response {
            print("her in resposne")

        }else if let data = data
         {
            print("here in data")
            print(data)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct

            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            print(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8))
            do {
              //  let todo = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: responseData)
              //  NSAssertionHandler(.success(todo))
            } catch {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                //print(error)
              //  NSAssertionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following method using `Alamofire`

```
Alamofire.request("yourSide", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

If it doesn't work, which is unlikely, use this following code

```
Alamofire.request("yourSide", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
```